# Rails 3 - Tempfile Path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following:

```
attachments.each do |a|
   Rails.logger.info a.filename
   tempfile = Tempfile.new("#{a.filename}", "#{Rails.root.to_s}/tmp/")
   Rails.logger.info tempfile.path
end
```

Where attachments is from paperclip.

**Here's the output:**

```
billgates.jpg
/Users/bhellman/Sites/cline/tmp/billgates.jpg20101204-17402-of0u9o-0
```

Why is the file name getting `20101204-17402-of0u9o-0` appended to at the end? That's breaking everything with paperclip etc. Anyone seen this before? For the life of I have no idea what's doing it?

Thanks

**UPDATE**
Paperclip: [Paperclip on github](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/)

a is the attachment file

```
tempfile = Tempfile.new("#{a.filename}", "#{Rails.root.to_s}/tmp/")
tempfile << a.body
tempfile.puts
attachments.build(
    :attachment => File.open(tempfile.path)
)
```

Comment: Why not just use File.new rather than Tempfile.new?

Comment: Good question. It needs to be Heroku friendly and their docs say to use tempfile?

Comment: Won't File.New break if there is a conflict?

Answer (score 29):

best make sure your tempfile has the correct extension, saving you to trying and change it after:

> file = Tempfile.new(['hello', '.jpg'])
>
> file.path  # => something like: "/tmp/hello2843-8392-92849382--0.jpg"

more here: http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_125/Tempfile/new/class

Answer (score 4):

The first argument for Tempfile.new is just a basename. To make sure each Tempfile is unique the characters are appended to the end of the file.

Comment: Thanks John, but that's breaking Paperclip, which then does :attachment => File.open(tempfile.path),    how can I send this tempfile to paperclip without all the randomness appended to the filename? thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do with paperclip. Are you trying to change the default path?

Comment: Here's what I have in Paperclip now: :attachment => File.open(tempfile.path),  The problem is paperclip uses the temp filename when it uploads the file to s3. So the file name needs to be cleaned/correct before sending to paperclip.

Comment: Can you send paperclip the temp file data and tell it the filename to use? Something like this: :attachment => send_data File.open(tempfile.path), :filename => "thefile.extttt"

Comment: Can you post the code where you used the :attachment option. I'm not familiar with this option.

Comment: I suggest you use File.new and make sure the filename doesn't already exist. Use "#{Rails.root.to_s}/tmp/#{n}/#{a.filename}" where n is an integer. Start n = 0 and increment until the file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Paperclip's API for this:

```
tempfiles = []
attachments.each do |a|
  # use Attachment#to_file to get a :filesystem => file, :s3 => tempfile
  tempfiles << a.to_file
end

tempfiles.each do |tf|
  Rails.logger.debug tf.filename
end
```

Comment: I'm not understanding what changes with the above suggestion? What's being done to avoid the crazy random filename given by Tempfile?

Comment: I thought your issue was that, when you pulled down files from storage, the tempfiles had odd filenames.

Comment: I create a tempfile, and then send that to paperclip to save the attachment via (:attachment => File.open(tempfile.path), it's there that paperclip gets the filename from the tempfile. That's the problem, bec the filename at that point from tempfile. has all the randomness at the end of it

Comment: the problem, sending the tempfile to paperclip to save in a way that doesn't have the crazy filename, but rather the original filename so paperclips saves it correctly on S3. does that help?

Answer (score 0):

```
attachment = attachments.build(
  :attachment => File.open(tempfile.path)
)

# change the displayed file name stored in the db record here
attachment.attachment_file_name = a.filename # or whatever else you like

attachment.save!
```

Comment: tried that but the problem with this is the filename on S3 does not get updated. just the filename in the db, which then esentially makes the link invalid, losing the file.

Comment: Either change the filename before saving the record or don't include the filename from the tempfile in the filename as S3 sees it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found to deal with this was to specify the file extension in the Paperclip attribute. For example:

```
has_attached_file :picture,
  :url => "/system/:hash.jpg",
  :hash_secret => "long_secret_string",
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml"
```

Note that the :url is declared as '.jpg' rather than the traditional `.:extension`.

Good luck!